# Download my Tumblr likes

Tags: backup, tumblr

I want to download all *Tumblr* posts I liked.

#### What to backup?

- For text/quote/link/chat posts: it must download the main content (i.e., text resp. a link).
- For photo posts (including photosets): it must download the **high-res** image(s).
- For audio/video posts: it should download the media, but this is not required.
- Bonus points if the download contains …

  - … text added to photo/audio/video posts.
  - … source URL and/or reblog URL (on which I liked the post).
  - … metadata like publication date, tags, likes count, notes count.

The **format** doesn’t matter (as long as it can be read/opened by common tools).

#### Formal requirements

- If it’s a **local client**: it should be FLOSS and run on GNU/Linux.
- If it’s a **web service**: it should work without having access to my account. So it should use the public list available from <https://www.tumblr.com/liked/by/`username`>.

Comment: See also on [webapps.se]: [Download Tumblr favorites](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33824/24166)

Answer (score 6):

I found that this little Ruby script works really well:
https://github.com/javierarce/tumblr-photo-export

It's easy enough to use in Windows, even if you don't know anything about Ruby.

1. Download and install a [Ruby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
2. go to the ruby install folder's bin and open a command prompt
   On my machine it's under `C:\ruby22\bin`
3. install the `httparty` gem:
   `C:\ruby22\bin\gem.bat install "httparty"`
4. Follow the instructions on the github page and create a new Tumblr App to get an API key (you don't need to provide all the information they request, most is optional).
5. Change the parameters at the top of the `export.rb` script.
6. Run the script `C:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe export.rb` and that's it.

Comment: Will this download the text attached to photo posts?

Answer (score 2):

I made this small native application which downloads all the Tumblr posts that you liked.

https://github.com/neuro-sys/tumblr-downloader-client

[image: Tumblr Downloader]

It only downloads image posts (and GIFs) at the moment, though. I or someone else can extend it to do other things you asked about, so feel free to send a pull request.

I built the binaries for Linux 64-bit, Windows 64-bit, and Mac OSX. If the builds do not work somehow, open an issue on the github page.

Answer (score 1):

As a more recent and better alternative, try [TumbleThree](https://www.jzab.de/content/tumblthree), it is able to download all types of posts and likes as well.
For Windows only though, as far as I know.