# Backup all of own Likes on Tumblr

Tags: osx, backup, tumblr

I am looking for a program that

- Downloads **all** images from my [likes](http://www.tumblr.com/likes) feed on Tumblr (login required)
- Works on Mac OS X / Terminal; can also be a browser add-on.
- If possible, I'd like it to be free

Comment: Related question for a Web app or a GNU/Linux client: [Download my Tumblr likes](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3225/60)