# A program to backup my Tumblr likes, including text posts

Tags: backup, tumblr

I'm looking to create an archive of my Tumblr likes. I'm aware of TumblThree and the various Ruby projects floating around on GitHub, but those only do images and videos. I need the text posts and the captions on videos and photos.

Requirements are:

- Backup of all post types (text, photo, quote, link, chat, audio, video)
- Captions and reblog additions are saved too
- I'm willing to provide the tool an OAuth or login

Comment: For others who missed it, the context here is that Tumblr is going to ban pornography starting December 17th, so a lot of the site is going to disappear overnight.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Download my Tumblr likes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3225/60)